# in iOS app, why does prepareForSegue occur before didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, ios5

I'm trying to change the cell behavior to:
    1) When Cell Tapped, Mark Cell as Complete with a check mark
    2) When Detail Disclosure Accessory button is tapped, perform the Segue.
    3) In tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: I have:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    AWDelivery *delivery = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [delivery toggleDelivered: delivery];
    [self configureCheckmarkForCell:cell withDelivery:delivery];
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (debugging) NSLog(@"[%s] [%d]", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
}
```

the deselectRowAtIndexPath is supposed to bypass the segue, but it's not.

NSLogs:
    a) at 2012-04-29 18:50:00.848 Delivery[3148:fb03] [-[DeliveryTVC prepareForSegue:sender:]] [168]
    b) at 2012-04-29 18:50:01.245 Delivery[3148:fb03] [-[DeliveryTVC tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]] [93]

note that 'didSelect' occurs after 'prepareForSegue'.

Any hints would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share your code. I have the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Very random but from your code example, I learned about `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and `__LINE__` macros. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you have your detail segue attached to the table view cell?  Instead, try dragging it between the two view controllers (the one containing the table and the one where you want it to go).

Then perform it manually (`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue"];`) when `tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`.

Comment: Can you please add some code to perform segue manually please! I have a same issue where I want to pass cell information to next view controller. Did you mean perform presenting modal viewcontroller manually or prepareforsegue method? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, whwever you need to in view controller, say: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"MySegue"];  that string should match the identifier you set up for the segue in IB. Let me know if you need additional detail.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to get the current tableview selection in prepareForSegue you can get it by accessing the UITableViewController's tableView ivar;

```
[self tableView] indexPathForSelectedRow]
```

Comment: Tapping the accessory button doesn't select the cell, so indexpath.row doesn't correspond to the correct cell for the tapped accessory.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ClaimDetailsSeque"])
    {
        DLog(@"destinationViewController %@",[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController]);
        //This syntax is needed when the seque is going through a Navagation Controller
        ClaimDetailsFormViewController* vc = (ClaimDetailsFormViewController*)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

        //This the the way to get the object from the selected row via the FetchedResultsController
        //this is needed because prepareForSegue is called before didSelectRowAtIndexPath
        NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [self->claimTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        ClaimHistory *object = [[self claimHistoryFetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

        MyClaimHistorySM *myCH = [MyClaimHistorySM new];

        myCH.policyNumber = object.policyNumber;
        myCH.policyStatus = object.policyStatus;
        myCH.claimNumber  = object.claimNumber;
        myCH.insuredName = object.insuredName;
        myCH.lossDescription = object.lossDescription;
        myCH.dateOfLoss = object.dateOfLoss;
        myCH.incidentCloseDt = object.incidentCloseDt;

        vc.claimHistorySM = myCH;

    }

}
```

[image: Seque on Storyboard]

Comment: The segue was created in IB by selecting the Table View Cell and dragging the Triggered Segues selection "connector" to the Navigation Controller.